# Why the fragment's context null inside lifecycleScope

Tags: android, kotlin, lifecycle, coroutine

I have trouble while using lifecycleScope inside fragment, I think if the fragment detached to activity, then the lifecycleScope will cancel the coroutine jobs.

I have read the lifecycleScope' code and I think that can not happen.
The only things I can do is add a precondition "isAdded" to workaround with this.

```
private fun updateUserInfo(user: User) = lifecycleScope.launch {
   textView.text = getString(R.string.foo)
}
```

this code throw

> java.lang.IllegalStateException androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.requireContext (Fragment.java:696)

I wish there're someone can help me to explain the lifecycleScope's mechanism.

Comment: At which point do you call `updateUserInfo()` the reason might be, that your Fragment is not yet attached to the Activity.

Comment: If the Fragment not attached to the Activity, the Fragment's lifecycleScope still run the children coroutine jobs?

Comment: Haven't try that, but I guess so, as Fragment's lifecycle starts in `onCreate` not in `onAttach`, which is the place, where context is attached

Answer (score 18, accepted):

lifecycleScope (same way as lifecycle itself) of Fragment is not always had context, context available only after onAttach and before onDetach, in case of retaining Fragment is alive after onDetach, so context can be null.

Because you not only access context, but also touching view, you should use `viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope`, this will allow you to start coroutine in Fragment's View lifecycle, so you always have context and it cancels onDestroyView

Comment: When using this scope, are launch() and launchWhenStarted() effectively the same?

Comment: Not the same if you launch it after/during onStop, launchWhenStarted will execute lambda only when Fragment is started again, launch will be executed immediately (view is not destroyed on Fragment pause/stop), but both would be cancelled onViewDestroy